# uiview over uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem when adding uiview under navigation controller. why my uiview is on top of uinavigationcontroller, I want to add my uiview under navigationController.[image: navc] this is my code.

```
let slideView = UIView()

view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Absensi"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage  = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-SemiBold", size: 20)]
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-back-line").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))


view.addSubview(slideView)
        slideView.backgroundColor = .red
        slideView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            slideView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            slideView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            slideView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            slideView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        ])
```

Comment: Try changing constraint as following: slideView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)

Comment: hey it work thank you. I was thinking it should be working even though without safeArea @OnkarK

Comment: `view.sendSubviewToBack(slideView)`

Comment: set  ``navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your constraints with respect to safe area.

Answer (score 1):

You should be add the topAnchor to safe area ->  `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    slideView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    slideView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    slideView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    slideView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

just try using frame instead of constraint..this code should work

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let slideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:
            navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0 + 20 ,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 80))

        slideView.backgroundColor = .red
        slideView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Absensi"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage  = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-SemiBold", size: 20)]
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-back-line").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))

        view.addSubview(slideView)            
  }
```